# Copy objects from NSArray to another NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, vk

i'm making an iOS app using [VKSdk](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk).
I want to copy data from response.json[@"items"](it's nsarray,response.json its nsdictionary) to my nsarray.
Here is my code:

```
VKRequest * getWall = [VKRequest requestWithMethod:@"wall.get" andParameters:@{VK_API_OWNER_ID : @"1"} andHttpMethod:@"GET"];
[getWall executeWithResultBlock:^(VKResponse * response) {
    _vk_array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:response.json[@"items"]];
     NSLog(@"%@",_vk_array);//shows null
     NSLog(@"%@",response.json[@"items"]);//shows ok
} errorBlock:^(NSError * error) {
    if (error.code != VK_API_ERROR) {
        [error.vkError.request repeat];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"VK error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

I also trying to use just this code

```
_vk_array=response.json[@"items"]
```

But it still shows "null". Am i doing something wrong?

PS:

```
NSLog(@"%hhd",([response.json[@"items"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]));//shows 1
```

Comment: "NSLog(@"%@",_vk_feed);//shows null" is this a typo error? are you trying to print something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use it to copy an array object into another array.

```
NSArray *copyArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:yourArray];
```

Thanks

Comment: You can just write [yourArray copy];

Answer (score 0):

```
[response.json[@"items" 
    _vk_array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:response.json[@"items"]];
     NSLog(@"%@",_vk_feed);//shows null
```

here you are assigning value to _vk_array But you are tracing value of _vk_feed.

Also, [response.json[@"items"  is incomplete.